# Max length for HTML <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, textarea

How to restrict the maximum number of characters that can be entered into an HTML `<textarea>`? I'm looking for a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `TEXTAREA` tag does not have a `MAXLENGTH` attribute the way that an
`INPUT` tag does, at least not in most standard browsers. A very simple and effective way to limit the number of characters that can be *typed* into a `TEXTAREA` tag is:

```
<textarea onKeyPress="return ( this.value.length < 50 );"></textarea>
```

**Note:** `onKeyPress`, is going to prevent any button press, **any button** *including* the backspace key.

This works because the Boolean expression compares the field's length
before the new character is added to the maximum length you want (50 in this example, use your own here), and returns true if there is room for one more, `false` if not. Returning false from most events cancels the default action.
So if the current length is already 50 (or more), the handler returns false,
the `KeyPress` action is cancelled, and the character is not added.

One fly in the ointment is the possibility of pasting into a `TEXTAREA`,
which does not cause the `KeyPress` event to fire, circumventing this check.
Internet Explorer 5+ contains an `onPaste` event whose handler can contain the
check. However, note that you must also take into account how many
characters are waiting in the clipboard to know if the total is going to
take you over the limit or not. Fortunately, IE also contains a clipboard
object from the window object.[1](http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20040315/156773.html) Thus:

```
<textarea onKeyPress="return ( this.value.length < 50 );"
onPaste="return (( this.value.length +
window.clipboardData.getData('Text').length) < 50 );"></textarea>
```

Again, the `onPaste` event and `clipboardData` object are IE 5+ only. For a cross-browser solution, you will just have to use an `OnChange` or `OnBlur` handler to check the length, and handle it however you want (truncate the value silently, notify the user, etc.). Unfortunately, this doesn't catch the error as it's happening, only when the user attempts to leave the field, which is not quite as friendly.

[Source](http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20040315/156773.html)

Also, there is another way here, including a finished script you could include in your page:

http://cf-bill.blogspot.com/2005/05/textarea-maxlength-revisited.html

Comment: Note that the onKeyPress function written above will prevent any text from being entered in the textarea once the character limit is hit -- no characters can be deleted.

A more robust snippet would allow the user to hit the max limit and then backspace to delete characters to get the text under the limit.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me and my bad arithmetics, but I have the impression that when using new lines in textareas, IE and FF behave differently from Chrome with regards to `maxlength`. Has to do with the `\r\n` vs. `\n` issue (when your text contains newlines)... Definitely, `maxlength` doesn't seem to work cross-browser-ish on Windows from my experience... But nothing new here, just same old buggy HTML/JS stuff...

Answer (score 7):

HTML5 now allows [`maxlength` attribute on `<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-maxlength).

It is supported by all browsers except IE <= 9 and iOS Safari 8.4. See [support table on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=maxlength).

Comment: @erdomester It is working on supported browsers. You can test in w3c link that I have provided.

Comment: I tried it out and it works even if I used maxlength="500px". But the link you provided was inactive when I posted that comment and the page that was displayed was (I guess) showing other attributes than the one shows now.

Comment: That link isn't to the W3C, it is W3Schools, which is known for putting out incorrect information.

Comment: @Toby yes you are right. I should have been more clear in my comment. Unfortuantely, I don't see the option to edit the comment.

Comment: To erdomester: maxlength for textarea works fine, but the syntax is maxlength="500", not 500px.

Comment: You may want to be aware that newline characters can be counted differently when using maxlength, depending on the browser. Take a look at [this explanation](http://ashleyglee.com/maxlength-on-html-textarea-form-element/) for further details.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function(){  
  $("#id").keypress(function() {  
    var maxlen = 100;
if ($(this).val().length > maxlen) {  
  return false;
}  
})
});
```

Reference [Set maxlength in Html Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459610/set-maxlength-in-html-textarea)