# Set maxlength in Html Textarea

Tags: html, input, textarea

How can I set the `maxlength` in a `textarea`? And why `maxlength` is not working  properly in `textarea`?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Before HTML5, we have an easy but workable way:
Firstly set an maxlength attribute in the textarea element:

```
<textarea maxlength='250' name=''></textarea>
```

Then use JavaScript to limit user input:

```
$(function() {  
    $("textarea[maxlength]").bind('input propertychange', function() {  
        var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxlength');  
        if ($(this).val().length > maxLength) {  
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, maxLength));  
        }  
    })  
});
```

Make sure the bind both "**input**" and "**propertychange**" events to make it work on various browsers such as Firefox/Safari and IE.

Comment: Resorting to use of HTML5 is not an answer. We expect cross-browser support. That makes this by far the most correct answer.

Comment: Note that this solution is not "pure" javascript, it requires use of JQuery. (In case you try it without JQuery, and wonder why it does not work.)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite work as expected for any newlines in the textarea. I'm guessing JavaScript is treating a newline as one character rather than two so when I try to insert a "max length" string into the database I get an error.

Comment: I might be wrong, but if I'm typing a short story, and am inserting text at the start of the text box, the end of the text will be getting chopped off as I type. Possibly without my knowledge.

Comment: Apparently Opera and IE < 9 does not support the `maxlength` property -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

Comment: @3Dom: "Resorting to use of HTML5 is not an answer." - Using the HTML5 doctype *is* supported cross-browser (they tested various doctypes to see what worked in older browsers), and using an attribute introduced in HTML5 with a JavaScript fallback for browsers that don't support it is cross-browser compatible too.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, the fact that a JS fallback is required for older browsers makes the exercise of using HTML5 a waste of time. If you have to use a JS fallback, you may as well use it for all browsers. Saves time, for now, until Microsoft stops making browsers.

Comment: @3DOM: maybe. I think that, in general, HTML5 features will eventually be supported everywhere, so I think you'll eventually want to add the HTML5 method. If you do it now at the same time as adding a fallback, then you can confirm the HTML5 method works where supported, and label which browsers the fallback is for, making it easy to know when to remove the fallback. Often the HTML5 alternative will simply be an attribute or a tag, meaning it doesn't take much time to add.

Comment: @3Dom: In this specific example, you need *something* to indicate what the maximum length of each `<textarea>` should be, so using the `maxlength` attribute doesn't take any more time than a non-HTML5 alternative. You might need slightly more time to make your code only run if the HTML5 feature isn't supported, but those tests are usually one-liners, so again, not much of a waste of time.

Comment: ***http://xiaoqing.me/2009/05/31/limit-html-text-area/ not found***

Comment: sorry I'll remove the link from the answer

Answer (score 19):

If you are using HTML 5, you need to specify that in your [`DOCTYPE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#doctype) declaration.

For a valid HTML 5 document, it should start with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

---

Before HTML 5, the [`textarea`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) element did not have a `maxlength` attribute.

You can see this in the [DTD/spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html):

```
<!ELEMENT TEXTAREA - - (#PCDATA)       -- multi-line text field -->
<!ATTLIST TEXTAREA
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  name        CDATA          #IMPLIED
  rows        NUMBER         #REQUIRED
  cols        NUMBER         #REQUIRED
  disabled    (disabled)     #IMPLIED  -- unavailable in this context --
  readonly    (readonly)     #IMPLIED
  tabindex    NUMBER         #IMPLIED  -- position in tabbing order --
  accesskey   %Character;    #IMPLIED  -- accessibility key character --
  onfocus     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element got the focus --
  onblur      %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element lost the focus --
  onselect    %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- some text was selected --
  onchange    %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element value was changed --
  %reserved;                           -- reserved for possible future use --
  >
```

In order to limit the number of characters typed into a `textarea`, you will need to use javascript with the `onChange` event. You can then count the number of characters and disallow further typing.

[Here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/textarea.html) is an in-depth discussion on text input and how to use server and client side scripting to limit the size.

[Here](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html) is another sample.

Answer (score 16):

simple way to do maxlength for textarea in html4 is:

```
<textarea cols="60" rows="5" onchange="if (this.value.length > 100) { return false; }"></textarea>
```

Change the "100" to however many characters you want

-EDIT- Changed to "onchange" as that's more inclusive of all ways of inputting data

Comment: There is other ways than typing to add text in a textarea, like pasting. This solution probably does not work for them.

Comment: Not only, it will prevent you to erase the characters once pasted or loaded in a number exceeding your max size (you would have to select and cut with the mouse...).

Comment: Inline javascript event binding is also not the most semantic way to go about implementing these restrictions.

Comment: Another issue about this solution, if character count reached to limit, there is no way to use keyboard anymore, even for `backspace`

Comment: @Frédéric you can use `onkeydown` instead of onkeypress to limit pasting too

Comment: @MattiaPaletti, you can paste without using the keyboard.

Comment: To avoid `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` idiosyncrasies use `onChange`, this will be fired both with mouse and keyboard events.

Answer (score 7):

As I said in a comment to aqingsao's answer, it doesn't quite work when the `textarea` has newline characters, at least on Windows.

I've change his answer slightly thus:

```
$(function() {
    $("textarea[maxlength]").bind('input propertychange', function() {
        var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
        //I'm guessing JavaScript is treating a newline as one character rather than two so when I try to insert a "max length" string into the database I get an error.
        //Detect how many newlines are in the textarea, then be sure to count them twice as part of the length of the input.
        var newlines = ($(this).val().match(/\n/g) || []).length
        if ($(this).val().length + newlines > maxLength) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, maxLength - newlines));
        }
    })
});
```

Now when I try to paste a lot of data in with newlines, I get exactly the right number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){  
  $("#id").keypress(function() {  
    var maxlen = 100;
    if ($(this).val().length > maxlen) {  
      return false;
    }  
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before HTML5 it's only possible to check this with JavaScript or by a server-side verification (better, because JavaScript obviously only works with JavaScript enabled...). There is no native max-length attribute for textareas.

Since HTML5 it's a valid attribut, so defining your doctype as HTML5 may help. I don't know if all browsers support this attribute, though:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){
  $("textarea[maxlength]")
    .keydown(function(event){
       return !$(this).attr("maxlength") || this.value.length < $(this).attr("maxlength") || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46;
    })
    .keyup(function(event){
      var limit = $(this).attr("maxlength");

      if (!limit) return;

      if (this.value.length <= limit) return true;
      else {
        this.value = this.value.substr(0,limit);
        return false;
      }    
    });
});
```

For me works really perfect without jumping/showing additional characters; works exactly like maxlength on input

Comment: This won't work properly in all browsers. Hard newlines in `<textarea>` elements aren't (or weren't; they may have fixed it) counted properly in Firefox and Webkit. Hard newlines must be *transmitted* as a CR-LF pair (per the spec), but Firefox and Webkit count hard newlines as only 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
   <textarea id="msgc" onkeyup="cnt(event)" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea> 
</p> 
<p id="valmess2" style="color:red" ></p>

function cnt(event)
{ 
 document.getElementById("valmess2").innerHTML=""; // init and clear if b < max     
allowed character 

 a = document.getElementById("msgc").value; 
 b = a.length; 
 if (b > 400)
  { 
   document.getElementById("valmess2").innerHTML="the max length of 400 characters is 
reached, you typed in  " + b + "characters"; 
  } 
}
```

maxlength is only valid for HTML5. For HTML/XHTML you have to use JavaScript and/or PHP. With PHP you can use strlen for example.This example indicates only the max length, it's NOT blocking the input.

Answer (score -2):

resize:none;
This property fix your text area and bound it.
you use this css property id your textarea.gave text area an id and on the behalf of that id you can use this css property.