# MaxLength attribute is not working in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, maxlength

The `maxlength` attribute (eg: `maxlength="160"`) on `textarea` is not working in Firefox, it works in Chrome however. Can this issue be solved somehow?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea - `maxlength` on `<textarea>` is supported as of Firefox 4. I checked in Firefox 11 and it is indeed working. Which Firefox version are you testing with?

Comment: onkeypress="if (this.value.length > 160) { return false; }" added this

Comment: Now try pasting text into the field or dragging some text into it with the mouse.

Comment: Yes. I tried it... But its not working onkeypress..

Comment: onkeypress is not working on copy paste..... What will do?

Comment: @Anupama: Consider reading my first comment, as well as my comment of the answer by Quentin.

Answer (score 0):

The `maxlength` attribute for `textarea` is new in the HTML 5 draft. It doesn't appear in the current recommendation.

For browsers that don't support that part of the HTML 5 draft, you have to use JavaScript. Examples can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459610/set-maxlength-in-html-textarea)

Comment: These examples won't work if the user pastes text or drags it into the text field, they also tend to create an extremely awkward user experience. I think that the only proper solution is checking text length (e.g. via `setInterval` to cover all input methods) and displaying a warning if maximal length is exceeded, not attempting to block user input.