# how limit user to write on textarea

Tags: php, html, ajax

i have textarea type like this

```
<textarea name="setting_footer" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

how can Writing is affixed to the page so that no more than 100 characters.

Comment: But you will, of course, have to validate it on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`MAXLENGTH`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/maxlength)

```
<textarea name="setting_footer" cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="100"></textarea>
```

Comment: To get this in IE, you'd need IE10.  That's a pretty slim percentage of IE users.

Answer (score 6):

Try, MaxLength

```
<textarea maxlength='10'></textarea>
```

http://jsbin.com/isevek/1/

For < IE 10 - [Set maxlength in Html Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459610/set-maxlength-in-html-textarea)

Just to be clear as well, make sure you validate server side as well.

Comment: Seems to work in Firefox, however doesn't work in IE8.  You should probably post a disclaimer.

Comment: I wasn't aware it didn't work in IE! Good catch. Added a link to a JS solution as well.