# How do I set a maxlength for Codeigniters form_textarea()?

Tags: html, forms, codeigniter, textarea, maxlength

I am trying to set a `maxlength` for the `form_textarea()` in Codeigniter.

I tried the following:

```
<?php

$options = array(
    'maxlength' => '100'
    );

?>

<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Profiel:');?></td>
<td><?= form_textarea('Profiel', $options,  $info['Profiel']);?></td>
</tr>
```

When I edit my form to edit the text in the textarea it says Array. So the text is gone and is replaced with Array.

But that is not working. 
Maybe I have to use Jquery?

Comment: Lol. but unfortunally that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter allows you to pass attributes into your form elements by way of an associative array.

Documentation for the form helper is here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Although I can see exactly what you're trying to do, there's one caveat with textareas.  From the documentation:

> **form_textarea()**
>
> This function is identical in all respects to the form_input()
>   function above except that it generates a "textarea" type. Note:
>   Instead of the "maxlength" and "size" attributes in the above example,
>   you will instead specify "rows" and "cols".

So, you need to pass rows and columns instead of maxlength for textareas.  Your code would look something like this:

```
$options = array(
    'rows' => 10,
    'cols' => 10
);
```

Comment: The strange thing is. I can set let's say 150 words. and when I edit the text in the textarea it says `Array`. Why is this?

Comment: Take a look at my edit Kees.  The documentation says that you can't use maxlength on a textarea but instead have to use rows/cols.

Comment: Okay. This is a better explaination than Maximkou's answer.

Comment: Yes the thing was. I don't know when the limit is like 100 or 120 when I set rows/cols. that remains unclear.

Comment: hmm. I still can type more than 100 words in the textarea, even when i set the rows/cols to 1

Comment: Maxlength isn't really an attribute that's well-supported in textareas in HTML5.  However, you can use a little piece of JavaScript to do so.  There's a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459610/set-maxlength-in-html-textarea with a few different code snippets.  It should be said: unless it's absolutely necessary to limit user input, it is better practice not to.

Answer (score 0):

```
form_textarea(array(
    'cols' => 1, 
    'rows' => 1
));
```

Comment: Please explain what that does. I read something in the docs about this, but why should this limit the maxlength?

Comment: what's stopping you add the attribute 'maxlength' to options?

Comment: Hmm, one solution - validation data

Comment: Not sure if that's going to work because then I have to edit my whole form and add things to the controller. I will try it with javascript.