# Setting max length of characters in form_textarea?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using code igniter (1st time) and creating a text area using echo. How can I set the max length of this text area to 10 chars?

Current code:

```
echo form_textarea('age', set_value('age', 0));
```

I seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808969/how-do-i-set-a-maxlength-for-codeigniters-form-textarea) that suggests something similar to the following:

```
$options = array(
    'rows' => 10,
    'cols' => 10
);
```

but I am not sure how to implement it to my current code?

I want to ensure that the max no of chars can be entered is 10?

EDIT:

I have done the following but it is not stopping the amount of characters I can 
    enter:

```
$options = array(
  'rows' => 10,
  'cols' => 10,
  'maxlength' => 10
);

echo form_textarea('age', set_value('age',0), $options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd set your `$options`:

```
$options = array(
  'rows' => 10,
  'cols' => 10,
  'maxlength' => 10
);
```

Then echo out your `form_textarea`.

```
echo form_textarea('age', $options);
```

However, if you're setting `$options` in your controller and the `form_textarea` is in the view, you do it like this:

```
  $data['options'] = array(
    'rows' => 10,
    'cols' => 10,
    'maxlength' => 10
  );

$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

and then `$options` can be used in your view.

Also as a side note, if you're trying to set the value, you can pass that into `$options` too!

```
$options = array(
  'rows' => 10,
  'cols' => 10,
  'maxlength' => 10,
  'value' => '0'
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my edit as I have tried to implement this and it is not stopping the amount of chars I can enter

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set the limits in options array like this

```
$options = array(
    'rows' => 10,
    'cols' => 10
);
```

This will limit the length to 10 characters

Now pass the array while creating the text area

```
echo form_textarea('age', $options);
```

This will create a text area with length limit 10

Comment: Can you please see my edit to the question, I tried something similar but it did not work,thanks

Comment: Set all the parameters in $options and pass the array while creating the text area likewise form_textarea($options);

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to enter any strings inside the parantheses like you have on your "Current code". You need to pass an array with all the information you need. You can find more information on this here: **[CODEIGNITER MANUAL - FORM HELPER](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)**. Something like this should work for you:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'age',
    'id' => 'age',
    'value' => '0',
    'rows' => '10',
    'cols' => '10',
);

echo form_textarea($data);
```

Comment: Can you please see my edit to the question, I tried something similar but it did not work,thanks

Comment: Hi, you dont need `set_value`, nor `age` in your `form_textarea()` since you can put all that information in your $options array. Let me know if you need further help with this.

Comment: thank you. can you show me the array in full? thanks

Comment: my answer above should you that. Have you tried setting it like that?