# How can I decrease the character count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to decrease the character count of the given text-area as user enters.
I used the below code

```
var txtArea = $('<textarea class="txtStyle"></textarea>').appendTo('.txtArea');
            var rem_txt = 500;
            var text = "Characters remaining";
            $('.txtStyle').keyup(function () {
                debugger;
                var txt_txtarea = $(this).val().length;
                rem_txt = rem_txt - txt_txtarea;
            });
                $('<div id="rem">' + text + '=' + rem_txt + ' </div>').appendTo('.txtArea');
```

But the div is not updating the value of count. please help [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lszd/1/)

Comment: You should also add `maxlength="500"` to `<textarea>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not updating the html inside your handler for the keyup, you're just recalculating the remaining amount and not updating the UI.

If you update the inner text inside the event handler you'll see the remaining text:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Lszd/4/

```
var lengthAllowed = 500,
txtArea = $('<textarea class="txtStyle"></textarea><div id="rem">Characters remaining ' + lengthAllowed + '</div>').appendTo('.txtArea');
$('.txtStyle').keyup(function () {
    var charsSoFar = $(this).val().length,
    remaining = lengthAllowed - charsSoFar;
    $('#rem').text('Characters remaining='+remaining);
});
```

You haven't handled when the maximum text has been reached though.

Comment: how can i restrict the values from textarea after 'remaining' becomes zero??

Comment: There are some questions already answered on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459610/set-maxlength-in-html-textarea

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you show the initial value outside the `keyup` function. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lszd/3/

Comment: how can i restrict the values from textarea after 'remaining' becomes zero??

Comment: @NithinViswanathan add the inline property `maxlength="500"`

Comment: pardon.. i didnt get u

Comment: @NithinViswanathan `$('<textarea class="txtStyle" maxlength="500">`

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the complexity of your code somewhat to this:

Markup:

```
<textArea class="txtStyle" maxlength="500"></textArea>
<div id="txtRemaining"></div>
```

Script

```
$('.txtStyle').keyup(function () {
      $('#txtRemaining').html('Characters remaining ' + (500 - $(this).val().length));
});
```

[Fiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lszd/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the content on each keyup event

```
var txtArea = $('<textarea class="txtStyle"></textarea>').appendTo('.txtArea');
var rem_txt = 500;
var text = "Characters remaining";
$('.txtStyle').keyup(function () {
    var txt_txtarea = $(this).val().length;
    rem_txt = rem_txt - txt_txtarea;
    $('#rem').html(text + '=' + rem_txt); // update the value of #rem
});
$('<div id="rem">' + text + '=' + rem_txt + ' </div>').appendTo('.txtArea');
```

Comment: the problem is actually the count is decreasing with 3

Comment: how can i restrict the values from textarea after 'remaining' becomes zero??

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the txt, also do not update rem_txt, which supposed to be const

```
//this should be a const
var rem_txt = 500;
var text = "Characters remaining";

$('.txtStyle').keyup(function() {

    var txt_txtarea = $(this).val().length;

    updateRemain(rem_txt - txt_txtarea);
});

function updateRemain(rem_txt) {

    var rem = $('#rem');
    if (!rem.length) {
        rem = $('<div id="rem"></div>').appendTo('.txtArea');
    }

    rem.html(text + '=' + rem_txt);
}

updateRemain(rem_txt);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/WRj5a/1/

Answer (score 0):

you don't update the value after keyup ...

add `$('#rem').html(text + '=' + rem_txt);` and you should be fine!

http://jsfiddle.net/artificialflow3r/5Lszd/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code like this

The main issue is that you are setting `rem_txt` to 500 subtracting any new characters from an amended value and not from 500. Your code should look a bit more like this

```
var txtArea = $('<textarea class="txtStyle"></textarea>').appendTo('.txtArea');
$('<div id="rem">Characters remaining = 500 </div>').appendTo('.txtArea');

var text = "Characters remaining";
$('.txtStyle').keyup(function () {      
    var rem_txt = 500 - $(this).val().length; //Calculate your new length from 500 each time
    if($('#rem')) $('#rem').html('Characters remaining = '+rem_txt);
});
```

I'm creating the div with the initial value in first and then in your keyup function amending it's HTML. You were previously trying to update the HTML for the div outside of the keyup event, so in fact it was only ever running that piece of code once.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lszd/8/)