# Allow keyboard shortcuts while limiting characters in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe which users can use to type and markup text with some html. I would however like to limit the amount of characters they can input.

To solve this I am using the following code:

```
iframeDocument.onkeypress=function(e){
 if(iframeDocument.body.textContent.length > 99 && e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 40 && e.keyCode !=37 && e.keyCode != 38
 && e.keyCode !=39 && e.keyCode !=17){
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
 return false;
 }}
```

This limits them to 100 characters while still allowing them to use markup without it affecting how many characters they can use. This method has two problems that I am having trouble solving.

1. Keyboard shortcuts like ctrl+c and ctrl+v are disabled when the limit is reaching.
2. Users are unable to highlight text and type another character to replace it when the limit is reached

How can I go about fixing these issues?

Comment: possible a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459610/set-maxlength-in-html-textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you limit the user to enter only 100 characters he can still  break it by disabling javascript. user can also edit the javascript or html with inspection tools. So this is not completely possible from client side. You have to validate on server side also. On your iframe you may have a textarea in that you can try this.

```
    <textarea onchange='this.value=(this.value.length<100)?this.value:"";' onkeypress='return (this.value.length<100);' >
    </textarea>
```

Comment: Will this still allow html tags though? I tried something similar by returning a substring value, but it would end up removing part of the tags rather than plaintext.

Comment: @Clint this will allow html tags because we didn't write any logic to prevent  hml characters.