# TextArea Maximum Length?

Tags: html, textarea, maxlength

Is it possible to set the maximum length of text in a `TextArea`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max length for html text areas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569/max-length-for-html-text-areas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, use this plugin
http://www.stjerneman.com/demo/maxlength-with-jquery

Answer (score 9):

Something interesting is that HTML5 have added the feature of maxlength to textarea, if HTML5 is something you are ok to use right now.

[W3C official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html#textarea.attrs.maxlength)

Demo:

```
<textarea maxlength="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: So if I don't put this does it mean the textarea doesn't have a max length ?

Comment: @SanVed Exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following format in HTML

```
<input type="text" maxlength="13">
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is re-usable for all text areas via one function and
it doesn't inform the user that he/she is typing too many characters, it prevents them from doing so, sort of like maxlength

The Function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function imposeMaxLength(Object, MaxLen)
{
  return (Object.value.length <= MaxLen);
}
</script>
```

Implementation:

```
<textarea name="myName" onkeypress="return imposeMaxLength(this, 15);" ><textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Textarea doesn't accept the maxlength.

I have created a javascript function to handle this on onchange event. On one of my solutions I avoid the submit on form onsubmit event.

The code bellow will avoid submit if the textarea has more than 255 caracters

```
<script>
function checkSize(){
    var x = document.getElementById('x');
    return x.value.length <= 255;
}
</script>
<form onsubmit="return checkSize()">
    <textarea id="x"><textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: but in this method can't press backspace ( can't delete after reached it's maxlength)

Comment: The method will only be called on submit, if you press backspace or other key, the method will not be called. If you submit, the data only will be sent to the server if the textarea has less than 255 characters.