# Set the max amount of chars in a textarea

Tags: php, javascript, html

I try to limit the number of chars that can be added to a textarea. I know I could just take the number of chars with a sub-string but I want to indicate the user that his text has reached the maximal length.

The maxlength-attribute seems to do exactly what I want but IE does not support it on our current version (I think its supported somewhere around IE9)

To circumvent this problem I integrated `onKeyPress="return(this.value.length < 160);"` which works fine to prevent a too long text however it also prevents the erasing or reedit of the text which is a huge problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569/max-length-for-html-text-areas

Comment: if your maximum input length is less that 255 characters then why not use <input type=text> ?

Comment: @DaveChen: the problem is not solved yet, if the text reached max user can't edit...

Comment: possible duplicate of [TextArea Maximum Length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116564/textarea-maximum-length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this javascript it is working for me and also useful to see left character.

```
function textCounter(field,cntfield,maxlimit) { 

    if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
    {field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit); }
    // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
    else
    {       
    //cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length; 
    cntfield.value = field.value.length
    }

}


html file
```

Also please add on `onKeypress` event of text area with below span to manage remaining character

```
<span class="alignright comments-req"><input type="text" name="textlen" id="textlen" value="0" class="counter-textfield">/500 <?php  echo $this->translate('LABEL_CHARACTER_USED');?></span>
```

Comment: How do I need to implement this function? Do I need to use <textarea class="textarea" name="name" id="id" onKeyPress="textCounter(id,idcntfield,160">?

Comment: Great seems to work perfectly! I really like the added bonus of a counter, and hopefully our users too;)

Comment: The counter seems to be one event delayed i.e. when I have 160 chars remaining and I add a char the counter is still 160 if I then the delete the char I get 159. I hope it is clear what my problem is

Comment: might be the counter you passed could be problem

Comment: yeah the counter seem to be delayed, any idea how I can fix that? I thought about adding +1 on the first event, however I can't determine if it is a ++ or -- action for the counter. I also thought that adding the onchange-event could solve this problem but it doesn't seem to resolve even once. Or is it because I still have the onKeypress-Event included? Any help in this issue would be really appreciated.

Comment: i have change my eveent

Comment: I searched for possible events and a combination of onKeyPress (if someone keeps pressing a button like "return") onKeyUp(otherwise the counter is delayed) and onChange (if somebody pastes text into it) seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can use jquery validation check this link
 http://jqueryvalidation.org/maxlength-method/


    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Makes "field" required having at most 4 characters.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/site-demos.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="myform">
    <label for="field">Required, maximum length 4: </label>
    <input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
    </form>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <script>
    // just for the demos, avoids form submit
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
      debug: true,
      success: "valid"
    });
    $( "#myform" ).validate({
      rules: {
        field: {
          required: true,
          maxlength: 4
        }
      }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I want to use the validation while the user is typing how can I do that?