# What is the maximum length of a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to increase (or set to a default number) the amount of characters a textarea can have.
I know there is a `maxlength` attribute for HTML5 but I am using an older version of HTML so this is not an option.

Is there any way to do this? What is the default maximum length of characters allowed in a textarea?

Comment: It is unlimited unless otherwise specified. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FHTML%2FElements%2Ftextarea

Answer (score -4):

The TEXTAREA tag does not have a MAXLENGTH attribute the way that an INPUT tag does, at least not in most standard browsers. A very simple and effective way to limit the number of characters that can be typed into a TEXTAREA tag is:

```
<textarea onKeyPress="return ( this.value.length < 50 );"></textarea>
```

For more detail refer the post

[Max length for HTML <textarea>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569/max-length-for-html-text-areas)

Comment: Copy paste from the above link .. :)

Comment: @downvoter, it's a code copied from that link. i also gave that link reference in my answer. is there any mistake in my answer to downvote?

Comment: This won't prevent user from pasting a text.

Comment: @Pavlo Oh. I thought it will prevent user from pasting a text. hehehe...